# What does a declaration of template look like when using the standard allocator in a template class?

Tags: c++, allocator

I saw some examples of using allocator as a class member in a template class. Such like:

```
template <class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T>> class myVector
{
public:
    ...
protected:
    std::allocator<value_type> _alloc;
    ...
private:
    ...
};
```

But the code still works when I delete the default-value template argument like `template <class T> class myVector`.
So do we need to add a default-value template argument when we have a allocator as class member? If the answer is yes, why?

Comment: The code you've shown does not use the `Alloc` argument, so deleting it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown is probably wrong: It should use the provided `Alloc` type to allocate, instead of hard-coding `std::allocator`. (And also take advantage of the empty-base-class optimization, to avoid increasing the container size if the allocator is an empty type)